# returning a list of instances by the foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two models, Owner and Contract. A contract has an instance of an owner, owner does not have a list of contracts. I'm trying to query my list of contracts, to return a list filtered by owner, ie, a list of contracts by owner.

I had tried to follow previous examples and use Criteria to write a custom query, but, following suggestions I've checked the docks and tried to use named queries instead, however, I'm still really struggling.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Named parameter not bound : ownerId; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : ownerId
```

My models look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Contracts")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Contract.allContractsByOwner",
                query = "SELECT c FROM Contract c WHERE c.owner.id LIKE :ownerId"
        )
})

public class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;

    @Column
    private double price;

    @Column
    private String deliverDate;

public Contract(Owner owner, double price, String deliverDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.price = price;
        this.deliverDate = deliverDate;
    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Owners")
public class Owner {
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Owner(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
```

my contractRepoImpl

```
@Service
    public class ContractRepositoryImpl implements ContractRepositoryCustom {


        ContractRepository contractRepository;

        @Autowired
        EntityManager entityManager;

        public List allContractsByOwner(Long ownerId) {
            List contracts = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT c FROM Contract c WHERE c.owner.id LIKE :ownerId", Contract.class)
                    .getResultList();
            return contracts;
        }
    }
```

which I name in my ContractRepo and ContractRepoCustom files, and then in my controller I map to it like so. But, when I query it in my browser I get the error in my terminal.

```
  @GetMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}/contracts")
    public List allContractsByOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") Long ownerId){
        return contractRepository.allContractsByOwner(ownerId);
    }
```

I appreciate this is probably beginners mistakes, I am trying to follow docs but get a bit stuck with syntax & where annotations need to go.

Comment: There is indeed no property named `owner_id` in the class Contract. 1. Don't unwrap the EntityManager: it has all you need to create and execute queries and you don't need a Session to do that. Learn JPQL: there is absolutely no need to use a criteria query for such a basic, static query. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. It should look like `select c from Contract c where c.owner.id  :ownerId`.

Comment: And don't close the session or the EntityManager. Spring does that for you. Please, read the Spring documentation. You have plenty of useless boilerplate code, **and** you ignore exceptions instead of throwing them.

Comment: That's better. Now just read the exception message. It says= "Named parameter not bound : ownerId". And indeed, your query has a parameter newed òwnerId`, and you never specify what the value of this parameter is. Before calling `getResultList(), you need to set the parameter.

Comment: thank you, I got there finally :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks JB Nizet, got there in the end

I added parameters to my contractRepoImpl

```
  @Service
    public class ContractRepositoryImpl implements ContractRepositoryCustom {


        ContractRepository contractRepository;

        @Autowired
        EntityManager entityManager;


        public List allContractsByOwner(Long id) {
            List contracts = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT c FROM Contract c WHERE c.owner.id = :ownerId", Contract.class)
                    .setParameter("ownerId", id)
                    .getResultList();
            return contracts;
        }
    }
```

that then produced a SQL error, which I fixed by changing my @NamedQuery from 'LIKE' to '=' in my Contract class...

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Contract.allContractsByOwner",
                query = "SELECT c FROM Contract c WHERE c.owner.id = :ownerId"
        )
})
```